# get an error 'ByRef argument type mismatch'

Tags: vba

I have the following code:

```
sub refresh()
dim result2 as string
dim m as integer
dim activeWS as worksheet
For m = 6 To 10
            code = activeWS.Cells(m, 8).Value
            result 2 = "lkdsjlfaksj" ;a query, I would just put a random string for now, and it would change every time based on value of m
            Call GetOTCStruc(result2, m)
            Next m
end sub
```

'then I do something on the other function, which I just eliminate the code for now

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetOTCStruc(result2 As String, m As Integer)


    ...
End Sub
```

However, it has an error highlight the part on  Call GetOTCStruc(result2, m); any ideas why?

Thanks!

Comment: The code you posted doesn't give that compile error.  It gives a bunch of other ones though.  Can you update the question to include the ***actual code that is failing***?

Comment: You never set activeWS,  result 2 should not have a space. Call is not needed and the () can be removed/

Comment: Verify **all modules** have `Option Explicit` specified. Most likely cause, you're passing an undeclared `Variant/Empty` with a typo in the name. Option Explicit catches that.